# Trig Identity Question Finding Value of K

Tags: proof-verification, trigonometry

If $\sin(x) + \cos(x) = k$ for what value(s) of $k$ can $\sin(x)\cos(x)=1$?

Answer (score 2):

hint
$$(\cos x+\sin x)^2=k^2$$
$$(1+2\cos x \sin x)=k^2$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$$\sin(x)=k-\cos(x)$$

$$\to\cos(x)(k-\cos(x))=1$$
$$\to k\cos(x)-\cos^2(x)=1$$
$$\to\cos^2(x)-k\cos(x)+1=0$$
$$\chi=\cos(x)\implies \chi^2-k\chi+1=0$$

Comment: Okay thanks how would I solve for K from the final equation?

Comment: You are looking for $k$ where the equation has a solution. You should use the discriminant for this.

Comment: @MilinPatel you'll notice something problematic since $\cos(x)+\sin(x)=k$. Don't worry; it is obvious from a graph that a solution requires $x\in \Bbb C$

Comment: By solving the discriminant I get a k val of +-2. Is that correct?

Comment: You're considering where there is only one solution. Two solutions is also okay. What would the range be then?

Comment: How do i consider range?

Comment: You want when $k^2-4\geq0$ so $|k|\geq 2$ (or $k\leq -2, k\geq 2$)